# How to add a death feature with collision detection?

Tags: java, collision-detection

(**Note**: This post was copy pasted from Game development because i got comments saying to post this at Stack Overflow)

What I want is that when my player collides with my Tiles(which are solid) they'll be sent to the menustate(or menuscreen). I already did collision detection for my tiles(with isSolid). So how to make it so that if my player collides with a tile(ones which are solid that is), it will be sent to my menustate.

and sorry if i added unwanted classes, its that my Player, Creature and Entity class extends to each other.

This is my Creatures Class where the Collision detection is present.

```
public abstract class Creatures extends Entity {

public static final int DEFAULT_HEALTH = 1;
public static final float DEFAULT_SPEED = 5.0f;
public static final int DEFAULT_CREATURE_WIDTH = 128;
public static final int DEFAULT_CREATURE_HEIGHT = 128;

protected int health;
protected float speed;
public static float xMove;
public static float yMove;
protected int MinHeight;

public Creatures(Handler handler, float x, float y, int width, int height) {
    super(handler, x, y, width, height);
    health = DEFAULT_HEALTH;
    speed = DEFAULT_SPEED; 
    xMove = 0;
    yMove = 0;
    MinHeight = -1;
}

public void move(){
    moveX();
    moveY();
}

//COLLISION DETECTION BELOW
public void moveX(){
    if(xMove > 0){//Moving right
        int tx = (int) (x + xMove + bounds.x + bounds.width) / Tile.TILEWIDTH;

        if(!collisionWithTile(tx, (int) (y + bounds.y) / Tile.TILEHEIGHT) &&
                !collisionWithTile(tx, (int) (y + bounds.y + bounds.height) / Tile.TILEHEIGHT)){
            x += xMove;
        }else{
            x = tx * Tile.TILEWIDTH - bounds.x - bounds.width - 1;
        }

    }else if(xMove < 0){//Moving left
        int tx = (int) (x + xMove + bounds.x) / Tile.TILEWIDTH;

        if(!collisionWithTile(tx, (int) (y + bounds.y) / Tile.TILEHEIGHT) &&
                !collisionWithTile(tx, (int) (y + bounds.y + bounds.height) / Tile.TILEHEIGHT)){
            x += xMove;
        }else{
            x = tx * Tile.TILEWIDTH + Tile.TILEWIDTH - bounds.x;
        }
    }
}

public void moveY(){
    if(yMove < 0){//Up
        int ty = (int) (y + yMove + bounds.y) / Tile.TILEHEIGHT;

        if(!collisionWithTile((int) (x + bounds.x) / Tile.TILEWIDTH, ty) &&
                !collisionWithTile((int) (x + bounds.x + bounds.width) / Tile.TILEWIDTH, ty)){
            y += yMove;
        }else{
            y = ty * Tile.TILEHEIGHT + Tile.TILEHEIGHT - bounds.y;
        }

    }else if(yMove > 0){//Down
        int ty = (int) (y + yMove + bounds.y + bounds.height) / Tile.TILEHEIGHT;

        if(!collisionWithTile((int) (x + bounds.x) / Tile.TILEWIDTH, ty) &&
                !collisionWithTile((int) (x + bounds.x + bounds.width) / Tile.TILEWIDTH, ty)){
            y += yMove;
        }else{
            y = ty * Tile.TILEHEIGHT - bounds.y - bounds.height - 1;
        }
    }
}

//This code below checks if the tile im colliding is Solid or not
protected boolean collisionWithTile(int x, int y){
    return handler.getWorld().getTile(x, y).isSolid();
}

//GETTERS AND SETTERS

public float getxMove() {
    return xMove;
}

@SuppressWarnings("static-access")
public void setxMove(float xMove) {
    this.xMove = xMove;
}

public float getyMove() {
    return yMove;
}

@SuppressWarnings("static-access")
public void setyMove(float yMove) {
    this.yMove = yMove;
}

public int getHealth() {
    return health;
}

public void setHealth(int health) {
    this.health = health;
}

public float getSpeed() {
    return speed;
}

public void setSpeed(float speed) {
    this.speed = speed;
}

}
```

Then My Entity class(my Creature class extends to this class)

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;

public abstract class Entity {

protected Handler handler;
protected float x, y;
protected int width, height;
protected Rectangle bounds;

public Entity(Handler handler, float x, float y, int width, int height){
    this.handler = handler;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;

    bounds = new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height);
}

public abstract void tick();

public abstract void render(Graphics g);

public float getX() {
    return x;
}

public void setX(float x) {
    this.x = x;
}

public float getY() {
    return y;
}

public void setY(float y) {
    this.y = y;
}

public int getWidth() {
    return width;
}

public void setWidth(int width) {
    this.width = width;
}

public int getHeight() {
    return height;
}

public void setHeight(int height) {
    this.height = height;
}

}
```

My Player class( my player class extends to my Creature class)

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class Player extends Creatures{

//Animations
private Animation animRight, animLeft;

public Player(Handler handler, float x, float y) {
    super(handler, x, y, Creatures.DEFAULT_CREATURE_WIDTH, Creatures.DEFAULT_CREATURE_HEIGHT);

    bounds.x = 32;
    bounds.y = 32;
    bounds.width = 92;
    bounds.height = 96;

    //Animations
    animRight = new Animation(100, Assets.DerpDino_right);
    animLeft  = new Animation(100, Assets.DerpDino_left);
}

@Override
public void tick() {

    //Animations
    animRight.tick();
    animLeft.tick();
    //Movement
    getInput();
    move();
    handler.getGameCamera().centerOnEntity(this);

}

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private void Dead(){
   //what to put in here
}

private void getInput(){
    xMove = 6;
    //Gravity
    yMove = 6;
    MinHeight = 0;

    if(handler.getKeyManager().left)
        xMove = -speed;
    if(handler.getKeyManager().right)
        xMove = speed;
    if(handler.getKeyManager().jumping)
        //this makes my player fly
        yMove = -speed;
}

@Override
public void render(Graphics g) {
    g.drawImage(getCurrentAnimationFrame(), (int) (x - handler.getGameCamera().getxOffset()), (int) (y -handler.getGameCamera().getyOffset()), width, height, null);    


private BufferedImage getCurrentAnimationFrame(){
    if(xMove < 0){
        return animLeft.getCurrentFrame();
    }else{
        return animRight.getCurrentFrame();
    }
}

}
```

Tile Class(where isSolid() is)

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class Tile {

//STATIC STUFF HERE

public static Tile[] tiles = new Tile[256];
public static Tile grassTile = new GrassTile(0);
public static Tile cactusTile = new CactusTile(1);
public static Tile dirtTile = new DirtTile(2);
public static Tile skyTile = new SkyTile(3);
public static Tile cloudTile = new CloudTile(4);
public static Tile caveTile = new CaveTile(5);
public static Tile stoneTile = new StoneTile(6);

//CLASS

public static final int TILEWIDTH = 128, TILEHEIGHT = 128;

protected BufferedImage texture;
protected final int id;

public Tile(BufferedImage texture, int id){
    this.texture = texture;
    this.id = id;

    tiles[id] = this;
}

public void tick(){

}

public void render(Graphics g, int x, int y){
    g.drawImage(texture, x, y, TILEWIDTH, TILEHEIGHT, null);
}

//HERE!!
public boolean isSolid(){
    return false;
}

public int getId(){
    return id;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer!!!I just added `State.setstate(menustate)` at if my player collides with the block, find the ***//here*** in my code.

```
public boolean moveX(){
    if(xMove > 0){//Moving right
        int tx = (int) (x + xMove + bounds.x + bounds.width) / Tile.TILEWIDTH;

        if(!collisionWithTile(tx, (int) (y + bounds.y) / Tile.TILEHEIGHT) &&
                !collisionWithTile(tx, (int) (y + bounds.y + bounds.height) / Tile.TILEHEIGHT)){
            x += xMove;
        }else{
            x = tx * Tile.TILEWIDTH - bounds.x - bounds.width - 1;
            State.setState(handler.getGame().menuState);//here!!!
        }

    }else if(xMove < 0){//Moving left
        int tx = (int) (x + xMove + bounds.x) / Tile.TILEWIDTH;

        if(!collisionWithTile(tx, (int) (y + bounds.y) / Tile.TILEHEIGHT) &&
                !collisionWithTile(tx, (int) (y + bounds.y + bounds.height) / Tile.TILEHEIGHT)){
            x += xMove;
        }else{
            x = tx * Tile.TILEWIDTH + Tile.TILEWIDTH - bounds.x;
            State.setState(handler.getGame().menuState);//here!!!
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public boolean moveY(){
    if(yMove < 0){//Up
        int ty = (int) (y + yMove + bounds.y) / Tile.TILEHEIGHT;

        if(!collisionWithTile((int) (x + bounds.x) / Tile.TILEWIDTH, ty) &&
                !collisionWithTile((int) (x + bounds.x + bounds.width) /     Tile.TILEWIDTH, ty)){
            y += yMove;
        }else{
            y = ty * Tile.TILEHEIGHT + Tile.TILEHEIGHT - bounds.y;
            State.setState(handler.getGame().menuState);//here!!!
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make an enum called STATE, which will contain and handle your game states.

```
public enum STATE {GAME, MENU};
public STATE state = STATE.GAME;
```

In your game loop, you have to implements if statements.

```
if (state == STATE.GAME) {
    // game logic here
} else if (state == STATE.MENU) {
    // menu logic here
}
```

Also do not forget to add these in your graphics, what should render when the state is set to game and what when it is set to menu.

Then you should call:

```
if (collisionWithTile) {
    state = STATE.MENU;
}
```

Comment: I already made states(not with enum), and if you want me to add it to my post then tell me.

Comment: So what is the problem? If an entity collides with a tile, then set the state to menu. Explain the problem further, then I will be able to help you better.

Comment: I dont know how to do it

Comment: and i did collision detection like `moveX()` and `moveY()`, check the Creature class on my post to know more

Comment: and that `if (collisionWithTile) { state.setState(handler.getgame.menuState)} doesnt work. what it does is when i collide with any tile, it sends me to the menuscreen. so basically when i play my game, after a few millisecond, it sends me back to my MenuScreen

Comment: Okay, I can help you if you send me your source code. Give me the link to the files, I will run it on my computer and see what is going on with your game.

Comment: your email please

Comment: Send the link here, please.

Comment: I know what you have to do. You said that the state should change to MENU when you collide with a block that is solid. So your if should be

Comment: `if (collisionWithTile && tile.isSolid)`

Comment: If you store your tiles in an ArrayList, you have to loop through your ArrayList and put the if statement into it.

Comment: thats clever but didnt work. You see when i do that, i must make my `public boolean isSolid()' to static which lets my player walk through the solid tile.

Comment: @SreeLegend make a `public boolean isSolid;`in your Tile class. In your Tile constructor, add `boolean isSolid`, and then `this.isSolid = isSolid;`. When you are adding a Tile into the `ArrayList`, just put there true or false, depends on you, if you want the tile to be solid or not. Then, do as I said before, put into if statement this: `if (collisionWithTile && tile.isSolid)`. This is the way I do it, and it works just fine for me.